# install mongodb_river plugin then face this ERROR: Could not find plugin descriptor 'plugin-descriptor.properties' in plugin zip

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

**C:\elasticsearch-2.1.2\bin>plugin.bat install richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/2.0.6**

**-> Installing richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/2.0.6...**

Trying //[download.elastic.co/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/elasticsearch-river-mongodb-2.0.6.zip][1] ...

Trying //[search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/2.0.6/elasticsearch-river-mongodb-2.0.6.zip][1] ...

Trying //[oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/2.0.6/elasticsearch-river-mongodb-2.0.6.zip][1] ...

Trying //[github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/archive/2.0.6.zip][1] ...
Trying //[github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/archive/master.zip][1] ...
Downloading ............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................DONE
****Verifying https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/archive/master.zip checksums if available ...**

**NOTE: Unable to verify checksum for downloaded plugin (unable to find .sha1 or .md5 file to verify**)**

**ERROR: Could not find plugin descriptor 'plugin-descriptor.properties' in plugin zip**

Comment: question is not clear.

Comment: plz give me answer  above question